# Postman Get request to curl

Tags: curl, postman, php-curl

Hi I'm new to this and wondering if you could help me I tried postman get request I've successfully sent the get request and I got the response that I want but when I try to use code snippet like php curl or curl it gives me an error when J execute those code snippets

Here is the curl snippet from postman

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://fakecez.xyz/random/goblok.php' \
--header 'accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
--header 'accept-encoding:  gzip, deflate, br' \
--header 'accept-language:  en-US,en;q=0.9' \
--header 'referer:  https://go.gets4link.com/' \
--header 'user-agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9.5.4; SM-G298S Build/MMB29K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/181.217 Chrome/47.0 Mobile Safari/537.3'
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: The code won't execute

Comment: Can you post what the output from Postman is?

Comment: When I replace your url with google, its work. 
when I check you URL I get "404". 
Are you sure it worked on postman with that URL ? 
maybe you need to add a connection token...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.